# Cross browser web application

Tags: php, cross-browser

I have to develop a website compatible for mobile devices as well as desktop etc. Now i have two options from the search i have done. Either i make a separate application for mobile devices or i develop one for all(obviously with less glitter) and let the browsers manage how they render it.

Now my question is simple. What problems will i encounter if i make one site for all? or why should i make a separate site fore mobile. My target platforms are all the latest versions of Mac OS, Linux, Android, iOS etc.

EDIT : My site has a lot of visual effects like sliders and sidebar gadgets that involve lot of js and HTMl. Other than that it is supposed to be a CMS-based site like in Wordpress or Drupal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Today's and most of yesterdays desktop and Mobile browsers are perfectly capable of rendering sites with as much glitter as possible. I'd make a responsive design single site.

Comment: What problems will you encounter?  No idea!  We have no idea what you intend to build.  This kind of question is very specific to the application.  You haven't provided enough details to expect a useful answer.

Comment: @Brad Sorry man. My site has a lot of visual effects like sliders and sidebar gadgets that involve lot of js and HTMl. Other than that it is supposed to be a CMS-based site like in Wordpress or Drupal.

Comment: @hussain I stick by my earlier statement with the addition: If it's not necessary on a mobile device/smaller screen, hide it with a responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depend on the site. if its simply information site with only text and some images then it will be better to develop single site for both the devices in responsive manner but in case the site has high multimedia content like video,flash,mp3 or high resolution images it will be better to create separate sites for both desktop and mobile  as its hard to load multimedia content in mobile.

And Also mobile site should target only on main part of the site. Its should have only important part of the site.Mobile site should be short and sweet. Easy to use and easy to load.

Comment: Yes i totally agree for a mobile site to have just the most important part.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CSS media queries
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/, http://mediaqueri.es/
or frameworks like http://jquerymobile.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an acceptable answer:

Today's and most of yesterdays desktop and Mobile browsers are perfectly capable of rendering sites with as much glitter as possible. I'd make a responsive design single site.

If it's not necessary on a mobile device/smaller screen, hide it with a responsive design.